# Is there any potential problem when using two Telethon scripts for two different Telegram accounts in the same IP?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I was wondering for my project if Telegram could send me a delay or ban if I'm using two Telethon scripts each of them connecting to a different Telegram account in the same machine?

They will just be reading messages, nothing too fancy. At the moment one has been running without any issues.

Thank you

Comment: Keep in mind that hosting multiple bots on 1 IP could result in faster rate limits by telegram.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit on the number of different accounts you can have on the same IP/machine. Telegram uses sockets to connect so if a limit existed it would be related to the number of active connections your machine can handle.